# inserting td in a tr with ID using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to insert a td inside a tr which has a ID using javascript.Can someone please help me or guide me in the right direction.Sorry it might be simple but I m very new to javascript.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function insertText ()
   {
       //function to insert any text on the tr with id "tr1"
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="javascript:insertText()">
  <table>
   <tr id="tr1">
    </tr>`
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this an assignment question? I saw a very similar one earlier today.

Comment: I m not in college anymore :)

Comment: No problem :) Just a couple of hours ago I saw a question for an assignment that had a nearly identical structure and goal as yours, with similar skeletal code posted.  We do occasionally see multiple classmates of the same course post the same assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function insertText ()
{
    var td = document.getElementById('tr1').insertCell(0);
    td.innerHTML = "Some Text";
}
```

The main advantage of [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/tableRow.insertCell) (and [insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.insertRow)) is that they allow you to specify an index where the new cell (or row) is to be inserted.

Comment: +1 Wow, I didn't even know about `insertCell`, I usually just append like in @heartcode's answer.

Comment: especially useful for inserting cells in specific positions (updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function insertText ()
{    
    var el = document.createElement('td');
    el.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
    document.getElementById("tr1").appendChild(el);
}
```